# How to set up my input data on a specific cell in Userform?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want to start adding data from a specific cell and stop at another cell. From I7:I10 to T7:T10. 
But I want to enter the data from the Userform. But whenever I entered the data, it is saying I am on Cell 16,000 something.

I have two data set, and one tab in the userform work well, it would enter the data in rows. But for the other tab, I would like it to enter it by the next column. I have data below I7 by the way. But some of the areas are blank and some with data. 
One of the tabs from Userform is going to a separate sheet called Employee and the other going to TestCal.

```
Private Sub CBSave_Click()

Dim lrEmp as Long
Dim lrCal as Long

'This part work fine
lrEmp = Sheets("Employee").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Sheets("Employee")
    .Cells(lrEmp + 1, "A").Value = tbEmpID.Text
    .Cells(lrEmp + 1, "B").Value = tbName.Text
    .Cells(lrEmp + 1, "C").Value = tbLast.Text
End With

'This is the part I am having trouble with
lcCal = Sheets("TestCal").Range("Sales") .End(xlToLeft).Column
With Sheets("TestCal")
     .Cells(lrCal, "I").Value = tbApple.Text
     .Cells(lrCal + 1, "I").Value = tbOrange.Text
     .Cells(lrCal + 2, "I").Value = tbBanana.Text
End With

End Sub
```

I think I set up my column one wrong, how would I set it up where the next data entry will go to the right. Right now, the data entry is being inputted all the way down to the 16,000 cells for some reason.

**Forgot to mention this, tbApple, tbOrange, and tbBanana are all in the same column. I want to get the next column with them like that.

I hope I am making sense. Thank you.

Comment: On your line `lcCal=` you should have `xlToLeft` instead of right.  You are going to the last column every time.  You should also put `Option Explicit` above your sub.  You will see that not all your variables are declared and you are mixing them up.  `lcCal` and `lrCal`.

Comment: In addition, where you are using `lrCal`, you will have two column identifiers, which will give you odd results.  You will want the row, then column.

Comment: Ok, so I just updated the code a little bit.  I created a table of the area where I want the data to be filled in ("Sale"). Now I do not know how to set it up to go to the next available column.

Comment: I set up lrEmp because it is in a different sheet and that I want it to enter the data by row, but for lcCal is in a different sheet and I want that to fill in data by column. Sorry for it being a little complicated. @DarrellH

Comment: `lrCal` is not declared nor set.  I gave you an answer below.

Comment: Yes i see, thank you. I mistyped it actually, it is IrCal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where 7 through 10 comes from, maybe 7 is a header?

```
'This is the part I am having trouble with
lcCal = Sheets("TestCal").Cells(7,columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
With Sheets("TestCal")
     .Cells(8, lcCal).Value = tbApple.Text
     .Cells(9, lcCal).Value = tbOrange.Text
     .Cells(10, lcCal).Value = tbBanana.Text
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The data is going from left to right, but thank you. This work now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find the column to the right of the last used column, try this:  Two sheets, one named Testcal and one named Main.

```
Private Sub TestCal()
lccal = Sheets("TestCal").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
Sheets("Main").Cells(1, 1) = lccal
End Sub
```

This returns the column to the right of the rightmost used column of whichever row you choose in Testcal.

Comment: It said object doesn't support